# Is separate thread a good strategy to terminate application with background tasks by keypress?

Tags: java, console, kbhit

I've a console Java application, which does some tasks in the background. Java doesn't support console kbhit() for testing if there is something in keyboard buffer and as I know all console reads and tests are blocking.

What I'm going to do is to start a background thread with something like console.readLine() and then put some termination flag after this blocking call is finished. Application background tasks will check this flag and decide whether they need to terminate.

BTW, my application is going write to console during its work (logging via logback and such), but never read it.

Is such strategy a good one?

Comment: to me, dedicating a thread to `console.readLine()` sounds like a good approach...have you tested it? the only thing you'll need to worry about is synchronizing on the flag.

Comment: @sthupahsmaht Which flag? Console is already synchronized in Java

Comment: and I quote, "What I'm going to do is to start a background thread with something like console.readLine() and then put some termination flag after this blocking call is finished. Application background tasks will check this flag and decide whether they need to terminate."

Comment: @sthupahsmaht Ah, well, but what's the point synchronizing it, if it is written by only one thread (the one that waits for console input)? All others will just read it.

Comment: at least declare it `volatile`, otherwise you run the risk of never seeing the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `System.in.available()>0` but that only buffers full lines (after pressing the enter key) from the console

Comment: What if key pressed was Enter alone? Will available() return something > 0?

Comment: yeah System.in also buffers the linebreaks so pressing only enter will put available to 1 (or 2 in windows))